# Createa loop for new values in new df in R

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I have a df with 1500 obs. and 100 variables.
These are shares and I would like to calculate the EMA50 for all 100 shares and have them in a new df. I would like to put this in a loop, because I want to plot each share + result after that. But the plot is not important for now. To show the whole process better I have made an example: (Probably there is an easier way to code this example, but I am in the middle of my studies and still learning to code in R.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
library(fPortfolio)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
#
DStart <-  "2016-01-01" 
DEnd <-  "2020-12-31" 
#
#loading DAX and MDAX Index data from Yahoo Finance
TSLA <-  getSymbols("TSLA", src="yahoo", from=DStart, to=DEnd,  auto.assign=FALSE) 
AAPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="yahoo", from=DStart, to=DEnd,  auto.assign=FALSE)
AMZN <- getSymbols("AMZN", src="yahoo", from=DStart, to=DEnd,  auto.assign=FALSE)
#
Closing <- merge(TSLA, AAPL, AMZN)
#
write.zoo(Closing, file="Closing.csv", sep=",", dec="." )
#
df_Closing <- Closing[,-c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,17,18)]
```

I now have all closing prices in a df like in my real df.
For the individual calculation of the EMA I use:

```
df_Closing$TSLA_EMA50 = EMA(df_Closing$TSLA.Close,50)
```

During my search I came across several solutions, which all ended in error messages until now.
My last attempt looked like this:

```
df_EMA50 <- df_Closing
for (i in names(df_Closing)) {
  j <- EMA(df_Closing$i,50)
  new_df[i] <- j$EMA50
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically easier to iterate by position instead of by name.  The output `data.frame` should be initialized empty to make it easier to identify problems and ensure expected output.

```
df_EMA50 <- df_Closing[0, ]
for (i in seq_len(ncol(df_Closing))) {
  j <- EMA(df_Closing[, i], 50)
  colnames(j) <- colnames(df_Closing[, i])
  df_EMA50 <- cbind(df_EMA50, j)
}
```

Comment: perfect. thank you! is it possible to implement also a plot to it? So it makes a plot for every single stock with the EMA50?

Comment: @Qncy You can generate a plot at the same time or in a subsequent step.  Using `plot` will display and allow to save to a picture.  If you need to save the plot then likely you'll need to look at `ggplot2`.

Comment: thank you. i just getting this error atm for my real df: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply different number of rows: 0, 1520 maybe you have a solution for this too. @manotheshark. I just see that my i at the values ist just 1L instead of 96

Comment: The `i` with a value of `1L` means it's likely failing during the first iteration.  Step through each step of the loop; my initial guess is that there wrong with the data.frames and `cbind`.